# While returning a DataContract from a WCF function, I'm getting this error: "An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response"

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

Here are my data contracts:

```
[DataContract]
public class Claim : IDisposable
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ClaimID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Stream ClaimImage { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (ClaimImage != null)
        {
            ClaimImage.Close();
            ClaimImage = null;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class ClaimInformation
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> Documents { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
}
```

I have an OperationContract that takes a "ClaimInformation" and returns a list of "Claim." Which is just two integers and an image that is broken down into a stream.

```
[OperationContract]
List<Claim> ProcessDocument(ClaimInformation ClaimInfo);
```

ProcessDocument calls a method in a class.

```
public List<Claim> ProcessDocument(ClaimInformation ClaimInfo)
{
    List<Claim> FinishedClaimList = new List<Claim>();

    Document doc = new Document();
    FinishedClaimList = doc.ProcessDocument(ClaimInfo);

    return FinishedClaimList;
}
```

That method is too large for me to post here. But it's just this:

```
public List<Claim> ProcessDocument(ClaimInformation ClaimInfo)
    {
```

Inside of the method, it creates a new "Claim" and adds it to the "ClaimList."

```
ClaimList.Add(new Claim { ClaimID = ClaimID, ClaimImage = this.GetStream(newdoc.FullName), PageNumber = pageNum });
```

And finally, this is how I'm calling it all:

```
OCREngine.IEngine engine = new OCREngine.EngineClient();
OCREngine.ClaimInformation CI = new ClaimInformation();
CI.Documents = ImageNames;
CI.TotalPages = cc.lbClaims.Items.Count;

ClaimList.Add(engine.ProcessDocument(CI));
```

I'm just creating a new client for the service and then instantiating a new ClaimInformation DataContract. I set the ImageNames property, which is just a list of strings and then I add an integer to the TotalPages.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty generic exception in WCF so you'll need to [enable WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to get more detailed info.

Just guessing but look at [this MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/17981e4c-8210-4baf-855a-8040139846cf) where the list contained complex objects that exceeded the default internal object limits in WCF. Once you enable WCF tracing, you should have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept this as the answer. It told me the real exception, which I Googled and appear to have gotten an answer.